# Where can I obtain 3D data for Singapore?

Tags: dem, 3d, footprint, singapore

I am looking for providers of 3D maps/models of Singapore.

This might be either from photogrammetry/laser techniques or based on a DEM + building footprints/landuse with a height attribute.

Is any such data available either in public repositories or from specialized companies?

Answer (score 2):

Well this is almost certainly against Google's [Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/earth/license.html), so I'm definitely not recommending it, but I found an interesting method of extracting Google Earth building models to [OBJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) files here: [Google Earth to OBJ Using GLIntercept](http://brian-horning.com/google-earth-to-obj-using-glintercept/)

[image: Screenshot of captured cityscape in Maya]

If you can wait, the [Singapore Land Authority](http://www.sla.gov.sg/htm/hom/index.htm) is [reportedly](http://www.futuregov.asia/articles/2013/dec/13/singapore-develop-3d-national-topographic-model/) in the process of developing a 3D togographic dataset. I found a specifications document [here](http://www.sla.gov.sg/doc/new/Standard_and_Specifications_for_3D_Topographic_Mapping_in_Singapore_Version1_Nov_2013.pdf). They also have 2D data available [here](http://data.gov.sg/common/search.aspx?ag=1).

Comment: thanks; but google earth is currently failry limited on Singapore 3D buildings.

Comment: SLA indeed recenlty filled a tender for their 3D topographic model.